# Abrir Página depois que a Progressbar chegar a 100%

Tags: javascript, carregamento

Olá gostaria de uma ajuda, tenho um botão que quando é pressionado dispara o evento da `progressbar` e ela começa a carregar ate 100%, depois disso gostaria de abrir uma página (por exemplo de agradecimento). o HTML e o Script estão logo abaixo;

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>ProgressBar com JavaScript </h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Finalizar</button>
```

Comment: Você já fez a verificação quando chega em 100, basta abrir a janela ali. Qual foi a dificuldade?

Answer (score -2):

Se eu entendi direito é só você utilizar o comando `window.open()` dentro do `if (width >= 100)`  passando dentro dele a `url` da sua página e o modo como ela vai abrir:

```
window.open("https://previews.123rf.com/images/aliasching/aliasching1411/aliasching141100033/33389018-congratulations-typography-lettering-decorative-text-card-design.jpg","_self");// url de uma imagem "congratulations" que você poderá substituir pela sua página de agradecimentos.
```

Se você quiser saber mais sobre o método `open` do objeto `window`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Segue o exemplo:

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      window.open("https://previews.123rf.com/images/aliasching/aliasching1411/aliasching141100033/33389018-congratulations-typography-lettering-decorative-text-card-design.jpg","_self")
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>ProgressBar com JavaScript </h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Finalizar</button>
```

Comment: ótimo entendi, mas feito isso já com o php tudo certo ela ja enviaria o formulário?

Comment: ai você vai ter que dar um redirect no php, você não citou esse detalhe rsrs

Comment: está bem obrigado ai mano, consegui

Answer (score -2):

A parte mais difícil que é fazer a progress bar você já fez, agora basta abrir sua url:

**Redirecionar sua página atual para a url desejada**

```
//Altere para a url desejada
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
```

**Abrir uma nova aba no navegador com a url desejada**

```
//Altere para a url desejada
window.open('https://www.google.com');
```

**Aplicando no seu código algum dos exemplos acima**

```
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
          clearInterval(id);

          //Altere para a url desejada
          window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
      } else {
          width++; 
          elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      }
   }
}
```